# Why is my Discord bot showing online but not working?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently making a discord bot. I pasted some codes that I previously wrote that works fine last time, but it is not working now.

```
#LINK FILES
import bot_token
import task
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

#LIBRARIES
import discord
import os

#VARIABLES
token = bot_token.token
client = discord.Client()

#CODE
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have log in as {0.user}'. format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hi'):
        await message.channel.send('hello')

client. Run(token)
```

When I run the code, it shows that the bot is online, but when I send !hi in the server, the bot has no reaction. May I know whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your bot have the required permissions and intents to read messages?

Permissions need to be set in the discord developer portal and need to be agreed on by the server owner when the bot is added to a server. This specifies what your bot is allowed to do.

Intents specify what information you want the bot to receive from discord. You can try:

```
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True)
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

or

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

If either permissions or intents are missing, your bot will not receive any messages and thus not react to them.

Comment: Hmm...It shows this error

`Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000174D98F5D80>`

But I don't think it is the bot permission's problem as I gave administrator permission to the bot

Comment: could you please post the full error traceback?

Comment: Nevermind, I found my problem. I double-checked the bot permission and found that I haven't set the permission yet. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the message_content intent.
Make sure you have it enabled in your bot's application page.

```
intents = discord.Intents(message_content=True)
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've found my problem.  I double-checked the bot permission and found that I haven't set the permission yet.