# My discord bot is online but doesnt get any interaction

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My Discord bot is online and no errors are shown, but there is no interaction at all with the "/". I've confirmed that the token and ID are correct since my bot is online when I start "node." in the terminal. However, I don't know why there is no interaction. Here is the bot's code:

```js
require('dotenv').config();

const { Client, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const { GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates,
  ],
});

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync('./commands')
  .filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

// Add the new command here
for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
  if (command.data) {
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
  }
}

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot is ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
  if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

  const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

  if (!command) return;

  try {
    console.log(`Executing command: ${interaction.commandName}`); // Debug statement

    await command.execute({ client, interaction });

    console.log(`Command executed successfully: ${interaction.commandName}`); // Debug statement
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    await interaction.reply({ content: 'An error occurred while executing the command.', ephemeral: true });
  }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

I also have `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "musicbot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/builders": "^1.6.3",
    "@discordjs/opus": "^0.9.0",
    "@discordjs/rest": "^1.7.1",
    "@discordjs/voice": "^0.16.0",
    "discord-api-types": "^0.37.45",
    "discord-player": "^6.5.0",
    "discord.js": "^14.11.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.1.4",
    "prism-media": "^1.3.5"
  }
}
```

You can also see the `play.js` code below for the commands:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { QueryType } = require("discord-player");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("play")
    .setDescription("Plays a song.")
    .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
      subcommand
        .setName("search")
        .setDescription("Searches for a song")
        .addStringOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("searchterms")
            .setDescription("Search keywords")
            .setRequired(true)
        )
    )
    .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
      subcommand
        .setName("playlist")
        .setDescription("Plays a playlist from YouTube")
        .addStringOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("url")
            .setDescription("Playlist URL")
            .setRequired(true)
        )
    )
    .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
      subcommand
        .setName("song")
        .setDescription("Plays a song from YouTube")
        .addStringOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("url")
            .setDescription("Song URL")
            .setRequired(true)
        )
    ),

  async execute({ client, interaction }) {
    if (!interaction.member.voice.channel) {
      await interaction.reply("You need to be in a voice channel.");
      return;
    }

    const queue = client.player.createQueue(interaction.guild);

    try {
      if (!queue.connection) await queue.connect(interaction.member.voice.channel);
    } catch (error) {
      queue.destroy();
      await interaction.reply("Failed to join the voice channel.");
      return;
    }

    await interaction.deferReply();

    const subcommand = interaction.options.getSubcommand();

    if (subcommand === "song") {
      const url = interaction.options.getString("url");

      const track = await client.player
        .search(url, {
          requestedBy: interaction.user,
          searchEngine: QueryType.YOUTUBE_VIDEO,
        })
        .then((x) => x.tracks[0]);

      if (!track) {
        await interaction.editReply("No results found.");
        return;
      }

      queue.addTrack(track);
      await interaction.editReply(`Added **${track.title}** to the queue.`);
    } else if (subcommand === "playlist") {
      const url = interaction.options.getString("url");

      const tracks = await client.player
        .search(url, {
          requestedBy: interaction.user,
          searchEngine: QueryType.YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST,
        })
        .then((x) => x.tracks);

      if (!tracks.length) {
        await interaction.editReply("No tracks found in the playlist.");
        return;
      }

      queue.addTracks(tracks);
      await interaction.editReply(`Added ${tracks.length} tracks to the queue.`);
    } else if (subcommand === "search") {
      const searchTerms = interaction.options.getString("searchterms");

      const tracks = await client.player
        .search(searchTerms, {
          requestedBy: interaction.user,
          searchEngine: QueryType.AUTO,
        })
        .then((x) => x.tracks);

      if (!tracks.length) {
        await interaction.editReply("No results found.");
        return;
      }

      queue.addTrack(tracks[0]);
      await interaction.editReply(`Added **${tracks[0].title}** to the queue.`);
    }

    if (!queue.playing) await queue.play();
  },
};
```

Comment: [Check bot's permissions.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73611064/14945696)

Comment: I did check the bot's permissions. It is admin + it has access to commands.

Answer (score 1):

First, your bot must have permissions to create slash commands in servers:

Go to [discord developers portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) -> OAuth2 -> URL Generator -
Then check if `applications.commands` scope is checked and invite the bot on your server with a new link

Then, you need to register the slashcommands -> https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-deployment.html#command-registration

Your bot should put the commands (globally or on 1 guild) to discord to display them to users:

```js
[...]
await rest.put(
    Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),
    { body: commands },
);
[...]
```